# Change words in application depending on language setting

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a application that is connected to a server. My application has to be multi-language so i have language files on my server. I need to change the language of my words to the language setting they choose.

What is the best way to do this?
Should i use the isolated storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establish a set Key/Value pair of known keys you will use in your app, and their value.

Then, create a `Dictionary<string,string>`

Then, create all the keys, and backup text just in case.

Serialize the entire dictionary in one piece using a BinarySerializer like [Sharp Serializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html)

Then, `serialize` the `Dictionary` in the form

```
strings.default
```

Then, have your server return XML, JSON, etc with the keys / values, and the language.

```
<strings language="en-us">
<string name="start">start</string>
</strings>
```

serialize this to disk in another dictionary:

```
strings.en-us
```

Then, when the app starts up, decide the language, grab the file from disk, and whenever you need to use strings, Key them in the dictionary. Storing the entire dictionary at once will prevent the performance of going to disk over and over again.

//create an interface for your strings. This will allow you to create a DesignTime version which doesn't rely on your server / implementation.

```
public interface IStringDictionary
    {
        string Start { get; }
        //the rest of your strings
    }
```

//Create a Implementation of your dictionary.

```
    public class StringDictionary : IStringDictionary
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary;

        public StringDictionary(string languageName = "default")
        {

            DictionaryLanguage = languageName;

        }

        public string Start
        {
            get { return _dictionary["start"]; }
            //your predefined key here, (should probably fallback / return null, or something)
        }



        private string _dictionaryLanguage;

        public string DictionaryLanguage
        {
            get { return _dictionaryLanguage; }
            set
            {
                if (_dictionaryLanguage == value) return;
                _dictionaryLanguage = value;
                _dictionary = LoadFromDisk("strings." + value); //create this method
            }
        }



    }
```

//create a mock version

```
public class MockStringDictionary : IStringDictionary

{  
     public string Start { get { return "start"; } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respone. This helped me out very much.